# add parameters to html.actionlink

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller "myController" that has a function called "printDetails(string id)"
I have a view that calls the

```
@Model.myControllers
//I output files here and user can download to a file, or by selecting an item from the drop down menu and pass it to the function "printDetails"
html.actionlink("download","printDetails")
html.dropdownlist("fromdb",null,"--select--", new{onchange="myJSFunction(fromdb)"})

<script>
myJSFunction(fromdb)
{
//how do i pass "fromdb" as a paramenter to "printDetails?id=fromdb" //myController/printDetails
}
</script>
```

thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an id to your ActionLink and then select it using jQuery :

```
  <%= Html.ActionLink("download", "printDetails", "MyController", null, new {id = "someID" }) %>
```

this will generate an html link :

```
 <a href="/MyController/printDetails" id="someID">download</a>
```

And then select your link using jquery and change href attribute :

```
$('#someID').attr('href','/MyController/printDetails?id='+fromdb);
```

Using pure Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('someID').href='/MyController/printDetails?id='+fromdb;
```

Comment: excellent, can i do it with simple js, somehow jquery isnt running for me and i don't have time to find out why:(

Comment: cool, so in my controller doing printDetails(string id) will know is the id fromdb? cool. thanks.